# Location added to Finder Favorites on OSX Mavericks keep disappearing

Tags: macos, finder, osx-mavericks

In the Finder (on OSX Mavericks) the locations I have added to ‘Favorites’ keep disappearing. In the image ‘workspace’ and ‘Dropbox’ disappears. Any idea how to fix this?

[image: Finded with Location added]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known bug. To solve that problem follow these steps:

1. Go to the Finder "Go"-Menu.
2. Hold the Option-Key and choose Library.
3. Open the preferences-Folder and delete the following files.

   > com.apple.finder.plist
   >
   > com.apple.sidebarlists.plist
4. Restart your computer.

The problem should be gone. You have to set your finder-settings again, but the favorites shouldn't disappear anymore.

Comment: c0dev, I was having the same issues and tried this. It worked for a short period of time. Although when I left my computer for a brief meeting and came back, I clicked on a folder I had added to 'Favorites' and it disappeared. Assume I've added a network folder to 'Favorites". In my case I've been connecting to my network's server after signing in on VPN first. I can access my work on a network folder and as long as the computer does not go to sleep, the files I added to 'Favorites' remain. The minute the computer goes to sleep however, my connection to the server is lost (VPN remains connecte

Comment: The same, this solution could solve my problem but it will occur again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove or upgrade NTFS driver will to avoid this issue to happen again.